# How change the radio button hover color

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hover, radio-button

i am using this css code for hover color for the text area and inputs it works fine in all browsers except IE its show like the image below. How to set the radio button background only to transparent.

[image]

my css code:

```
 input:focus, input:hover, textarea:focus, textarea:hover {
 border: 0 none;
 background: blue;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're styling `input` directly, radiobuttons and checkboxes will also be targeted. An easy way to avoid that is to use the `:not()` selector like so: `input:not([type=radio]):not([type=checkbox]):not([type=submit]):not([type=image]):not([type=button]):focus`. Note that this doesn't work in IE<8(?) though.

Answer (score 2):

powerbuoy is right about that the input selector select checkboxes and radios in addition to the normal text boxes.
but i have a suggestion that you can use instead of his that will work in more browsers.
basically you can add a class to all your checkbox and radio buttons inputs.
so your checkbox and radio html becomes

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
<input type="radio" class="radio">
```

and then add the css to reset the style for the checkboxes and radios like that

```
input.checkbox, input.radio
{
    background:transparent;
}
```